# What type of interface to choose for python program?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have an idea to build handy application in python, that display some useful info (my current IP, my current tasks in work, future meetings) and monitor various activities (page updates at corp site, run background scripts to keep documentation up to date). But i have no idea about UI, and never write anything except CLI apps.

My current candidates:

- curses (could be good and simple UI, but lacks of docs:c)
- web (does in requires JS use? i never use it)
- complete GUI, such as PyQT (seems to be overhead)

What do you recommend?

Comment: Tkinter and wxPython should work. Please see [this page about Python Gui Programming Tkinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)